# Big-oh notation of while loop with multiplication of 0.8

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, big-o

I came across a lot of samples around teaching about the big-oh notation of a while loop and the multiplication of variable inside the loop. I still can't get the understanding right.

Codes like this
`for(int i = i; i <= n; i = i*2)` is considered as `lgn` because it manipulate the value by multiple of 2.

I have codes like this too

```
while(i>N) 
{
  i/=2;
}
```

which is also considered as `lgn` as both the variable are being manipulated by 2. However, do it means the same if i changed the codes to something like

```
while(x > 0.01){
    x = x* 0.8;
    y = y + x;              
}
```

The main concern is, safely say that the runtime complexity of this loop is `log base 0.8` ?

Or is it suppose to be `log base 1.25`?

I do understand that `log base 0.8` and `log base 1.25` is not defined therefore the run time complexity of the while loop technically should be is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of loops `n` is given by

[image]

Thus the base is indeed 1.25. However changes in the base only means a multiplicative factor overall, which does not affect the *complexity* of the algorithm, so it will still be `O(log n)`.